# Linux compatible LTE/4G modem WITH voice and texting support

Tags: linux, 4g

As one of probably many around the world, I managed to get a decent internet package with my mobile phone, and like to use that on my PC as well. The ISP doesn't mind this as long as data usage stays reasonable, and it's very nice to be able to SSH into things and do work on the go. 
SO I wanted to put this card in a separate LTE modem router, so I'd have a bigger antenna, stable fast wifi hotspot and less hassle overall, but unfortunately that means I lose the ability to make normal voice calls and usually also can't receive let alone send texts/SMS.

So I was looking for a LTE/4G modem (with preferably a large antenna or SMA connector) that I can plug into a small linux box (e.g raspi), that *also* supports voice calling and texts, so that I can use something like Freeswitch/Asterisk to route this to my phone over the hotspot connection, while also using the data connection on any other connected device.

Does anyone know a decent, linux-compatible LTE/4G modem, with voicecalling and texting support?